# Check same value over entire agentset

Tags: boolean, comparison, netlogo, agentset

I have a model with a bank network.
Every bank is connected with a link to every other bank.
I need to verify that no pair of banks have the same value for a certain bank attribute.

(This is because, since I need to subtract one from another and put the result at the denominator of an expression, I get a "division by zero" execution error if any two banks have the same value for that attribute).

In order to check for this, I put in the following line:

```
if (any? banks with [AttributeX = [AttributeX] of other banks]) [set same-risk-value-error? true]
```

and then I put a stop-execution line inside "go" (immediately after the call to the function where that particular attribute is set):

```
if same-risk-value-error? = true [stop]
```

But apparently it does not work, as the execution continues and I still get that "division by zero" error when it occurs.

After I get the error, I check on the Command Center for the specific bank pair that gives me the error.

This is what I get:

```
observer> show [AttributeX] of bank 63
observer: 0
observer> show [AttributeX] of bank 83
observer: 0
observer> show (any? banks with [AttributeX = [AttributeX] of other banks])
observer: false
```

So: both banks (bank 63 and bank 83) have the same value for AttributeX (the value is equal to 0 in this case), and yet I get a "false" when I ask whether there are any two banks in the entire agentset of banks with the same value for that attribute.

How come?

My obvious guess is that the check

```
(any? banks with [AttributeX = [AttributeX] of other banks])
```

even though grammatically correct, does not do what I want.

How should I write a boolean check line (giving me true/false) to check that no two agents in an agentset have the same value for a particular attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are comparing a number to a list.  `[atrributeX] of other banks` creates a list of all the attributeX of the other banks, while for each bank, AttributeX is a single value.  In comparing a single value to a list, NetLogo will always yield a `false`.  (It might be more appropriate if NetLogo issued a warning, but that is another issue.)

If each bank needs to check this, then you might try

```
(any? other banks with [AttributeX = [attributeX] of myself]
```

Since `myself` is a single agent, `[attributeX] of myself` will yield a single value.  On the other hand, if you simply need to know if there are any duplicate values of AttributeX among all the banks, the observer could simply ask

```
if length [AttributeX] of banks != length remove-duplicates [AttributeX] of banks
```